# How do you create a UTC time in C for a specific day, month and year?

Tags: c, date, utc, year2038

How do I create a UTC time in C for the following date:

1st July 2038

using standard ANSI C function calls (given that the `tm_year` element of the `tm` structure cannot be greater than 137) ?

Comment: It's not a bad programming question, if you ignore the specific, invalid in 32-bit, date given. I might split this into two questions, or rewrite the question text to highlight the 2038 problem.

Comment: Since the `time_t` type is implementation-defined, it is only 32-bit systems that have a problem in year 2038; most 64-bit systems have already migrated to 64-bit `time_t` values, and you probably need to worry about the sun burning up before that rolls over.  (Specifically: Solaris 10 - 64-bit code has `sizeof(time_t) == 8` and 32-bit code has `sizeof(time_t) == 4`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't.  The 32-bit ANSI C time_t rolls over in 2038.  It's like asking how you create July 23, 2003 in your old 2-digit-year COBOL system.

Comment: Just to make it clear July 2038 is out of range, it rolls over sometime in January 2038.

Comment: 2038 January 19, 03:14:07 UTC being the last second before it rolls over.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, that's 2^31-1 seconds (i.e. the largest possible 32-bit signed integer) after midnight on January 1, 1970.

Answer (score 2):

Others have noted that the particular date you give as an example falls beyond the maximum date/time representable by a 32-bit time_t, often referred to as the [Year 2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) problem. One solution is to use a 64-bit time_t, which some 64-bit POSIX systems do (linux amd64), and call `mktime`.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        struct tm future;       /* as in future date */
        time_t t;

        future.tm_sec = 0;
        future.tm_min = 0;
        future.tm_hour = 0;
        future.tm_mday = 1;     /* 1st */
        future.tm_mon = 6;      /* July */
        future.tm_year = 2038 - 1900; /* 2038 in years since 1900 */
        future.tm_isdst = 0;          /* Daylight Saving not in affect (UTC) */
#ifdef _BSD_SOURCE
        future.tm_zone = "UTC";
#endif

        t = mktime( &future );
        if ( -1 == t ) {
                printf("Error converting 1 July 2038 to time_t time since Epoch\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        printf("UTC time and date: %s\n", asctime( &future ) );

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try, making use of the following example :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
  struct tm *local;
  time_t t;

  t = time(NULL);
  local = localtime(&t);
  printf("Local time and date: %s\n", asctime(local));
  local = gmtime(&t);
  printf("UTC time and date: %s\n", asctime(local));

  return 0;
}
```

It should give you, the expected result.

Comment: -1 Doesn't do what David asked about (ignoring the roll-over aspect). 
t = time(NULL) get the *current* time, not an arbitrary time.
-1 for reusing a variable (local) in a confusing manner.